# Make expectation involving Brownian motion identically zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $f \in L^2(0,1)$ and $T>0$ be fixed. How can I choose $g \in L^2(0,T)$ such that
\begin{align*}
0\equiv \mathbb{E}^x\left[f\left(X_T\right) \chi_{\tau \geqslant T}+g(T-\tau) \chi_{X_\tau=1}\right] \ \ ?
\end{align*}
Here $\chi$ stands for the characteristic function of a set, $\tau := \inf\{t > 0 : X_t \not\in(0, 1)\}$, and $$
    \begin{cases}
    d X(s)= d B(s), & s \in[t, T], \\
    X(t) = x, 
    \end{cases}
$$
with $(t, x) \in[0, T) \times \mathbb{R}$ and $B(\cdot)$ a standard Brownian motion starting from $t$ (with $W(t)=0$).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want it to be zero?